# How to pass formulae to lm objects with weights?

Tags: r, lm

How come I cannot pass formulae to lm objects with weights when formulae are one level up?

```
n <- 100
x <- seq(n)
y <- x + rnorm(n)
dat <- data.frame(y,x)   

## Success With OLS when passing formula
form <- y~x
llls <- sapply( seq(x), function(i){
    reg <- lm(form, data=dat)
})

## Success with WLS when not passing weights
llls <- sapply( seq(x), function(i){
    weight_i <- dnorm( (x[i]-x)/2)
    reg <- lm(y~x, data=dat, weights=weight_i)
})

## Failure with WLS when passing formula 
form <- y~x
llls <- sapply( seq(x), function(i){
    weight_i <- dnorm( (x[i]-x)/2)
    reg <- lm(form, data=dat, weights=weight_i)
})
```

R version 4.0.2

Comment: haven't checked, but `lm()` probably looks for weights in the environment of the formula; you could use `assign()` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `lm` is trying to find `weights_i` inside either `dat` or the environment in which the formula was written. The simple solution is to create the weights as a temporary column in `dat`. This prevents writing variables to the global environment.

```
form <- y~x
sapply( seq(x), function(i){
    dat$weight_i <- dnorm( (x[i]-x)/2)
    reg <- lm(form, data=dat, weights=weight_i)
})
#>               [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]       
#> coefficients  Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2  
#> residuals     Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100
#> fitted.values Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100
#> effects       Numeric,78  Numeric,79  Numeric,80  Numeric,81  Numeric,82 
#> weights       Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100
#> rank          2           2           2           2           2          
#> assign        Integer,2   Integer,2   Integer,2   Integer,2   Integer,2  
#> qr            List,5      List,5      List,5      List,5      List,5     
#> df.residual   76          77          78          79          80         
#> xlevels       List,0      List,0      List,0      List,0      List,0     
#>               [,6]        [,7]        [,8]        [,9]        [,10]      
#> coefficients  Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2  
#> residuals     Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100
#> fitted.values Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100
#> effects       Numeric,83  Numeric,84  Numeric,85  Numeric,86  Numeric,87 
#> weights       Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100
#> rank          2           2           2           2           2          
#> 
#> ...etc
```

The good news is that this won't cause any permanent changes to `dat`, or to your calling environment:

```
head(dat)
#>           y x
#> 1 0.6125909 1
#> 2 1.5101739 2
#> 3 1.9893877 3
#> 4 4.6632718 4
#> 5 6.1132429 5
#> 6 5.2509379 6
```

Comment: Alternatively, add `environment(form) <- environment()` to OP's approach.

Comment: @Roland yes, that would work as well, though I would probably want a reason for all those extra keystrokes as opposed to just sticking `dat$` in front of `weight_i` in the OP's code. I don't think it would make a difference performance-wise, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Performance difference is probably negligible (although for large data, assignment into a data.frame is likely slower).

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a list that includes the all of the arguments and use `do.call()`.

```
form <- y~x
llls <- sapply( seq(x), function(i){
  l <- list(formula=form, 
            data = dat, 
            weights = weight_i <- dnorm( (x[i]-x)/2)
        )
  reg <- do.call(lm, l)
})
```